# How to use an auth token and submit data using Python requests.POST?

Tags: python, authentication, curl, python-requests

Using WheniWork's api, I need to use a token for authentication, and I also need to send data to create a new user. Does the order or name of arguments I send with requests.post() matter?

If I'm just using GET to pull information, I can have the url contain the thing I'm looking for, and then send a payload that is the token. For example:

```
url = 'https://api.wheniwork.com/2/users/2450964'
payload = {"W-Token": "ilovemyboss"}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print r.text
```

When I try to add a new user however, I'm either not able to authenticate or not passing the data correctly. The api reference shows this format for using cURL:

```
curl https://api.wheniwork.com/2/users --data '{"first_name":"FirstName", "last_name": "LastName", "email": "user@email.com"}' -H "W-Token: ilovemyboss"
```

Here's what I've written out in python (2.7.10) using Requests:

```
url = 'https://api.wheniwork.com/2/users'
data={'first_name':'TestFirst', 'last_name':  'TestLast','email':'test@aol.com'}
params={"W-Token": "ilovemyboss"}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, params=params)
print r.text
```

Can someone explain if/how data(the user) gets sent separately from authentication(the token)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!
The data (user dict) needs to be in quotes. I'm not sure if their API is expecting a string, or if that's how requests works, or what. But here's the solution:

```
url = 'https://api.wheniwork.com/2/users'
data = "{'first_name':'TestFirst', 'last_name':  'TestLast','email':'test@aol.com'}"
params = {"W-Token": "ilovemyboss"}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, params=params)
print r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the above problem by converting the data dictionary to JSON string by using `json.dumps`.

```
  data={'first_name':'TestFirst', 'last_name':  'TestLast','email':'test@aol.com'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), params=params)
  print r.text
```

Comment: Thanks Stijn for validating my answer and formatting it to look better.